# Simple "Hello World!" console application crashes when run by windows TaskScheduler (1.0)

Tags: windows, console-application, scheduled-tasks, windowless, crash

I have a batch file which starts multiple instances of simple console application (Hello World!). I work on Windows server 2008 64-bit. I configure it to run in TaskScheduler, at startup, and whether user is logged-in or not. The later configuration means that the instances will run without GUI (i.e. - no window).

When I run this task, some of the instances just fail, after consuming 100& CPU. Application event-log shows the following error: 
"Faulting module KERNEL32.dll, version 6.0.6002.18005, time stamp 0x49e0421d, exception code 0xc0000142, fault offset 0x00000000000b8fb8, process id 0x29bc, application start time 0x01cae17d94a61895."

Running the batch file directly works just fine. It seems to me that the OS has a problem loading too many instances of the application when no window is displayed. However - I can’t figure out why...

Any idea??

Comment: This issue has a fix:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/9102531c-cf60-4682-b014-c11a190b00f1?prof=required

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue has a fix, thanks to Microsoft expert:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/9102531c-cf60-4682-b014-c11a190b00f1?prof=required